# Is ${\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\},...\}} $ a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define M: 
$$ \emptyset \in M \wedge \forall x\in M \rightarrow \{x\}\in M $$
How to construct this set in ZFC system? 
I know the axiom schema of replacement and the definition of recursion, but first I need a function to produce this set. A function is a map of pairs, so M must be the subset of the function's codomain, which means I still need M before I use the function...

Comment: The elements $\phi$, $\{\phi\}$, $\cdots$ look to be countable only; I didn't see where contradiction arises if this is considered as a set.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to make recursive definitions in ZFC?

Comment: That is not a definition, it is a property. There are many sets with with property. What you seek is a minimal one.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Your definition can be satisfied by a countable set.  You can construct it from the set guaranteed to exist by the [axiom of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#7._Axiom_of_infinity) using replacement.  The structure of the infinite set from the axiom is slightly different, but you can define a function that takes the elements from it to yours.

Comment: But a function is a set of pairs, if there is such a function, its codomain must be the superset of M... It seems like a dead loop...

Comment: @Monoidz: To use replacement, you only need to describe the function (as a class) in the language of set theory; you don't need to prove it is a set.

Comment: Thank you very much! My textbook didn't say that. I'm planning to use Jech's book.

Comment: If I remember right (I was very young at the time), in the old days before Von Neumann the axiom of infinity *was* stated (by Zermelo?) as the existence of the very set the OP is asking about, and the natural numbers were defined as $0=\emptyset,\ 1=\{0\},\ 2=\{1\},\ 3=\{2\},\ $ usw.